# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, froala

I'm trying to add Froala editor to my project.

Problem only on production server(on localhost it works fine)
I'm using rails 4.1.0
In gemfile i'm have

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

In my assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require modernizr
//= require froala_editor.min.js
```

In new.html.erb file:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for :article do |f| %>
    <p>
        Title<br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        Content<br>
    <%= f.text_area :text, :id=>'content' %>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('div#content').editable({
      inlineMode: false
    })
  });
</script>
```

In application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case result is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

If i'm adding a string:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

result is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Please check view source of page and make sure jquery.min.js is added at the top

Answer (score 11):

The following is what I needed to do for Rails 6 (6.0.3.4 to be exact.)
[found at (all credit goes to): https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker]

1. Add jQuery to environment.
   `$ yarn add jquery`
2. Add below code in environment.js (<app_path>/config/webpack/environment.js)

   ```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
    )
   ```
3. Require jquery in application.js file. (/app/javascript/packs/application.js)
   `require('jquery')`
4. (Restart rails server to make sure everything gets loaded.)

Comment: this did not work for me but `environment.plugins.append...` did (not prepend)

Answer (score 10):

This was my solution:

Put this in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and install this gem file:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Does it still go there in rails 6? (I don't have an app/assets/javascripts directory- should I create one?

Answer (score 6):

Replace application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: I do not understand if turbolinks is so problematic, why nobody either takes care of it or gets rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

An solution working for me is:

Separate files

create assets/javascripts/jquery_init.js content :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.cookie
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
```

an call before aplication.js

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery_init" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", :async => !Rails.env.development?, "turbolinks-data-track" => true %>
```

Comment: strange but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

try switching these lines:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

will become

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you have the foundation added to the project?

In `app/assets/javascripts/aplication.js`

I had the same error

> $ is no defined

and I resolved by reloading the foundation js this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).foundation();
});
```

Comment: When I tried this method I then got an error stating that jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did, it worked for me:

Surround your script with `window.onload = function () { };` so your js will be executed only when the page load:

```
window.onload = function () {
  $(function() {
    $('div#content').editable({
      inlineMode: false
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: It works for me! Thanks. `window.onload` in native JS code, so, it should work in any browser.

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST ADVICE ON THE INTERNET.  Thank you.