# Multiple Uncaught Errors Using the react-rails Gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

To preface my question, I am following [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails) guide.

When trying to build a CRUD interface using Rails and React, I receive [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html) error when trying to create a new item:

> addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

I wasn't improperly adding a `ref` attribute to any JSX not inside of a `render` method, so I must have multiple copies of React within my asset pipeline.

Research yielded the following potential results:

1. Introducing [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or [Searchkit](http://www.searchkit.co), suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37670521) SO answer, seemed to be clunky workarounds for my simple CRUD interface.
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601630) unselected SO answer suggested removing the `//= require react` line from `./app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.  This proved to be unsuccessful.
3. Issue #671, from the official GitHub react-rails repo. [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/671), outlines the first part of my issue perfectly.  I followed this potential solution, which suggests removing the `//= require react-server` line of the `./app/assets/javascripts/server_rendering.js` file.  This lead to a new error, outlined below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Which I assume means that `react_server` not only contains a second copy of React, but also loads something vital for my AJAX calls.

For reference, here are the contents of `./app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
...
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require react
//= require components
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and `./app/assets/javascripts/server_rendering.js`:

```
//= require react_ujs
//= require react-server
//= require ./components
...
```

Where a set of ellipses, or `...`, are used to shorten known comment sections.

- Ruby version: 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859)
- Rails version: 5.1.1
- react-rails version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third potential answer, or removing the `//= require react-server` from `./app/assets/javascripts/server_rendering.js`, was a step in the right direction.

Removing this line doesn't yield a new issue, it just reveals another error you had the entire time.  `react_server` doesn't define the `$` variable for AJAX calls, the jQuery gem does.

Found [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails).  I am confident in this solution because the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

is a jQuery issue, as the AJAX calls you are probably making take a form referenced in their official doc. [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Therefore, after running `gem install jquery-rails` in your shell, your `./app/assets/javascripts/application.js` should look like this:

```
...
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require react
//= require components
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Your `./app/assets/javascripts/server_rendering.js` file should look like this:

```
//= require react_ujs
// require react-server
//= require ./components
...
```

Note that `require react-server` is commented out.

And make sure to follow the solution found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774650) SO answer regarding the `.\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb` file.